# Ruby - Set foreign key from global variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models called worequest and status.
worequests has_many statuses and status belongs to worequest.
The statuses table has a foreign key called worequest_id.

If someone is looking at a worequest, I want to allow them to create a new status record.

So, I created a button on the worequest show page.  I thought that I would save the worequest.id in a global variable like this and link to create the new status record:

```
<% $current_request = @worequest.id %>
<%= link_to 'New Status', new_status_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Then in the new status page, I have this code:

```
<% if $current_request == nil %>
    <%= f.input :worequest_id, :label => 'Request ID' %>
<% else %>
    <% f.text_field :worequest_id, :value => $current_request %>
    <% $current_request = nil %>
<% end %>
```

But, the worequest.id field in the status record ends up being nil.
I also tried:

```
<% f.input :worequest_id, :value => $current_request %>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Global variables are BAD!  Now I can't quite tell what you're trying to do here, but I can promise you that globals are not the way to do it.  Try adding `worequest_id=whatever` to your [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).  I believe the `link_to` function adds all unrecognised hash options to the query string, so it should be fairly painless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use sessions.

```
session[:worequest_id] = @worequest.id
```

Then when you get to the other page, just call the value back and put it in.

```
f.hidden :worequest_id, :value => session[:worequest_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mizuho.
I used the session idea:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :worequest_id, :value => session[:worequest_id] %>
```

Before your comment, I didn't have the = after the <%.  Once I put it in, it worked.